# Unable to update symfony version using composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I want to update the Symfony version of our app from 2.7.13 to 2.7.38.
I updated composer.json but when I try to update, it throws an error.

Command:

> composer update symfony/symfony --with-dependencies

Error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>      - phpunit/phpunit 4.7.7 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.38].

Comment: Please share your composer.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version of Symfony actively refuses to use `phpunit/phpunit` < 4.8.35 by using `conflict` in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.7.38/composer.json:

```
"conflict": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "<4.8.35|<5.4.3,>=5.0"
},
```

You should upgrade `"phpunit/phpunit"` to a newer version in your own composer.json. Make sure you're not explicitly requiring a conflicted version and run `composer update phpunit/phpunit` (or just `composer update` to update all dependencies)

Comment: thank you for the reply.. upgrading the phpunit version to a non-conflicting one in the composer.json file did the trick for me. :) Sorry for reverting late.

Answer (score 0):

Try requiring the phpunit/bridge:

```
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
},
```

Comment: That won't work, because that's only the bridge. Surprisingly, it won't require the actual phpunit package: https://github.com/symfony/phpunit-bridge/blob/master/composer.json. It doesn't remove the `phpunit/phpunit 4.7.7` requirement the poster has now.

Comment: Ok, but when looking at the standard edition, phpunit/phpunit is not in the composer file: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/v2.7.38/composer.json

Comment: That's true. Symfony doesn't require phpunit directly, because doctrine and monolog do.